# What is the probability that the cow will produce milk?

Tags: probability

> A cow can produce $5$ to $10$ liters of milk per day.
>
> What is the probability that the cow will produce:
>
> $(1)$ exactly $7.5$ liters of milk next day?
>   $(2)$ at most $7.5$ liters of milk next day?
>   $(3)$ at least $7.5$ liter of milk next day?

The answers are:
$(1)$ $0$
$(2) \frac{3.5}{6} = 0.58333333333 (?)$
$(3)$  $?$

What would be the answers of $(2)$ and $(3)$?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing the probability distribution.

Comment: Surely you don't think you've given enough information to solve this problem.

Comment: Because I can't answer the question; there isn't enough information.

Comment: Who says discrete random variables don't have this issue?  You are always told if you are rolling a fair die or a loaded die, for example.

Comment: Obviously we need to know the distribution.  Perhaps the cow delivers exactly $5$ a day.  Then the answers are $0,1,0$.  Perhaps the cow delivers exactly $7.5$ a day.  Then the answers are $1,1,1$.  Perhaps the cow delivers exactly $8$ a day.  Then the answers are $0,0,1$.  And so on.

Comment: The questions are all questions about the distribution.  How can one be expected to answer them without knowing what the distribution is?

Comment: For heaven's sakes.  Edit your post to ask a coherent and complete question.  No normal distribution is confined to $[5,10]$.

Comment: JUST.  STOP.  the barrage of comments, read Lulu's comment **and think about it**.  Looking at the timings on comments you obviously considered it for 2 minutes maximum (my guess would be, much less).  And don't tell me to put that in an answer, because you have some perfectly good answers in comments.

Comment: This is an odd way to learn. Badly phrased problems are not good starting points. I suggest getting a text and working the exercises.

Comment: @lulu, I already have. Working on problems requires good concept.

Comment: Also, we have to consider winter vs. summer. And how well behaved is the cow at the barn!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "A cow can produce 5 to 10 litres of milk a day" means that the possible values you can measure values between 5 and 10. The information that you are missing is how probable those possible values are, and that piece of information is *essential* to answering all of the questions you have asked.

For example, the following are 3 valid distributions given your stated problem:

A. With probability 0.98, the cow produces *exactly* 7.5 litres of milk. With probability 0.01, the cow produces *exactly* 5 litres of milk, and with probability 0.01, the cow produces *exactly* 10 litres of milk. Then your answers are (1) 0.98, (2) 0.01 and (3) 0.01.

B. The cow's milk production is uniformly continuously distributed between 5 and 10 litres. Then your answers are (1) 0, (2) 0.5 and (3) 0.5, because 0.75 is the mid-point between the two values.

C. With probability 0.5, the cow produces exactly 7.5 litres of milk. With probability 0.45, the cow's milk production is drawn from a uniform continuous distribution on (5, 7.5), and with probability 0.5, the cow's milk production is drawn from a truncated exponential distribution on (7.5, 10). Then your answers are (1) 0.5, (2) 0.45 and (3) 0.05.